# unattended-upgrades NVIDIA

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, updates, unattended-upgrades

I use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in my work.
For regular updates of the inbuilt "unattended-uprades" package.
When installing Ubuntu, I selected the option to download additional drivers.

When I check for updates.

```
$ apt update
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

```
$ apt list --upgradable
linux-modules-nvidia-510-generic-hwe-22.04/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.15.0-33.34 amd64 [***: 5.15.0-27.28]
nvidia-kernel-common-510/jammy-updates,jammy-security 510.73.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [***: 510.60.02-0ubuntu1]
```

How to update drivers automatically?

Comment: The question is unclear. These packages will be upgraded as any other packages. To upgrade them now, run `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question .. What entries to add / change in the unattended-upgrades configuration to make NVIDIA updates automatic.

Comment: You don't need to change anything. Security updates are enough. They will be upgraded automatically.

Comment: My unatended-upgrades configuration allows upgrades. Example nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades -> "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates"; In order for Docker to update itself to the latest version I had to add Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {"Docker:jammy";}; Otherwise, unattended-upgrades did not upgrade these packages.